# Can browsers resolve font-face conflicts

Tags: css, font-face

My site uses some fonts with the `@font-face` CSS tag.

However I'm trying to add some temporary CSS styling to my site for a holiday or season...

I'd like to change an accent font to a different font. I was wondering if it was possible to leave the original CSS and just let my seasons.css file override it. Can browsers resolve @font-face conflicts?

My original CSS would be like:

```
@font-face {
Font-family: 'accentfont2';
Src: url(example/font.ttf);
}
```

And then my seasonal CSS which will be positioned below the standard CSS will be like:

```
@font-face {
Font-family: 'accentfont2';
src: url(example/seasonalfont.ttf);
}
```

Would the browser resolve the conflict by using the seasonalfont.ttf rather than the font.ttf?

Comment: Did you try it? What happened? In theory, as long as the later selector is *more specific* than the earlier, the later style would be used. So long as you've not used `!important` anywhere, which would override all subsequent selectors for those elements.

Comment: @DavidThomas I have not yet tried it, andim not really using !important anywhere, I was just wondering...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They can... all I had to do was type the normal CSS and it worked. This question was looking for a recommendation/condemnation but whatever

Answer (score 0):

Just use !important at the end of your seasonal styles, this will override the normal ones.

so.......

```
@font-face {
Font-family: 'accentfont2';
src: url(example/seasonalfont.ttf) !important;
}
```

You would want to comment out the seasonal ones when you didn't want them though by putting /* at the start of the seasonal code and */ at the end, this will make them so they are ignored until you uncomment them by removing the /* and the */  .

---

One alternative would just be to comment out the normal font css and uncomment the seasonal one when you want to use it.

---

Option 3 would just be to replace the font file with the other one each season, this way you wouldn't need to dive into the css at all, just change it via ftp.

Comment: !important is not needed here, and would possibly introduce other, hard to find inconsistencies.